# For an "untrusted CA" certificate error, IE8 shows the cert status as OK?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, ssl-certificate

While accessing a particular website in IE8 on Windows XP, the certificate error is shown. In the certificate's General tab, the description says: 'This certificate can not be verified up to a trusted CA' but in the Certificate Status inside the Certification Path tab, it says: **'This certificate is OK'** . Can somebody please explain this behavior? To be more clear, I understand that the CA involved here is not trusted, but do not understand the significance of the 'OK' status.

Answer (score 0):

On investigating some more websites and certificates, I found that this status "This Certificate is Ok" comes when we have downloaded the certificate through the browser.